# Проблема при установке opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv

Всем привет!

После установки `pip install opencv-python` в папке `cv2` находятся следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее пытаюсь воспроизвести пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136257/how-to-get-image-from-video-using-opencv-python. Однако, как ожидалось, тщетно в том смысле, что функции cv2.VideoCapture нет.

```
python==3.6.3
```

Я как-то неправильно устанавливаю?

Comment: добавьте пример кода, запустите его с помощью `py cv2-example.py`. Добавьте вывод: `py -mpip show opencv-python` в вопрос.

Comment: @jfs, оказывается все работает.

Answer (score -1):

Как возможный вариант можно использовать:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

в терминале анаконды. Только не забудьте запустить терминал от имени администратора.

Comment: А если анаконда не установлена?